# Push to github repository is not working

Tags: git, github

I am getting an error "*fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/link:username/repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 400*" while I try to push some new files to repository. But I can do push on existing files which I pulled from the repository earlier. The problem is with the new files. I am using 'ubuntu 14.04 LTS' and my my commands on terminal are as follows:-

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "made some changes"
git remote add origin https://github.com/link:username/repo.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: https://github.com/username/repo use like this

Comment: already tried that one too..

Comment: https://github.com/cynerellc/pdfactionresult

Comment: @MuhammadNoman very funny..

Comment: Can you paste the complete URL here ? Seems like the way URL mentioned could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you checked --set-upstream option ? And why is `link:username` in url? AFAIK urls on github are like https://github.com/[your_user_name]/[repo].git

Comment: Isn't that `[your_user_name]` should be `[username_of_person_owning_the_repo]` ? Ex: If you are owning the project and if I am pushing the changes, username would be yours and not mine.